# How to dynamically attach date partition to a string in json file scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a set of Json array in the test.json file the array contains a file path. I want to dynamically attach today's date to the file name.

My JSON:

```
{
    "inputData": [
        {
            "name": "People",
            "path": "F:\\people_data_20200103.txt"
        },
        {
            "name": "Animals",
            "path": "F:\\animals_data_20200103.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above is my Json file and I loop through the array and read the file path. For now, I have hardcoded the date partition YYYYMMDD (20200103) but I want to change it dynamically it should take current date. How to code it.

Comment: add ***LocalDate.now().toString.replaceAll("-","")*** instead of hardcoded string ....

Comment: my json will be in the test.json file it won't in any scala class so how LocalDate.now() will work in .json file @kavetiraviteja

Comment: deserialize it in to list of objects then apply the logic mentioned and serialize it back to file. or put a place holder like $today$ and replace that placeholder with ***LocalDate.now().toString.replaceAll("-","")*** after reading it in scala code.